# How does one remove a deleted library from an apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to remove a deleted library from an apps script.

See this video demonstrating how trying to remove it just shows errors, but doesn't remove it.

http://screencast.com/t/6317qYQEVkhl

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2684), and one that unfortunately doesn't have any known workarounds.